# i want to get json data from map through ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

i am calling `map.php` by passing lat long from `ajax` `url` i need to get map place response from map

```
function getinfo(lat,lng){
                $.ajax({
                  url:"map1.php?lat="+lat+"&lng="+lng,
                crossDomain:true,
                type:'POST',
                dataType:'application/json',
                data:"{}",
                  success:function(data){
                  var len = data.results.length;
                  for(var i=0;i<len;i++ ){
                      console.log(data.results[i]);
                  }
                }
                });
              };
```

**error** is

> response is not defined, function is not trigger

Comment: You actually mean `response`? Or maybe `results`? Whatever your PHP script returned, does not appear to contain such a property.

Comment: The script you posted is JavaScript with what looks like JQuery style references, I see no PHP in your post.  Your data assignment, should it be "{}" or just {} ?

Answer (score 1):

I think your result is probably not in `JSON` format, so when jQuery tries to `parse` it as such, it fails. For more information about error you can catch the error with `error:` callback function.

```
error: function () {
 // your error handled inside this section
}
```

If you don’t want to get `JSON` data response please remove dataType attribute.

Other than that please check you backend return data object. Also check the structure of your response data.

The structure also can have error. Also you can check your `ajax` call using chrome debugger and catch the results and errors.

Comment: thank you, the result is in json only , i tried error function also  error:function(e){
                      console.log('error',e);
                    }   and instead ajax call i tried with fetch method also still not getting response from map.

Comment: now am getting this error e = {readyState: 0, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}